# genAESKeyFromPW() but in Java

Tags: java, coldfusion

I have been using the genAESKeyFromPW() function on cflib.org for a while.  I am now in need to convert this to straight Java.  I have already asked around, but decided to post it here to see if I can get any answers as well.

First, take a look at the [genAESKeyFromPW()](http://cflib.org/udf/genAESKeyFromPW)  on [cflib.org](http://cflib.org).

Looking at that I created the following Java code for testing.

```
String filename = new String("foo");
String salt = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(filename.getBytes()));
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(filename.toCharArray(),salt.getBytes(), 1024,128);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
System.out.println(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(secret.getEncoded())));
```

The Java code returns **uJvByU+ArEvtsb+7E1mblw==**

Calling genAESKeyFromPW('foo',tobase64('foo')) returns  **7ZX9TKD8WVUlgTtbL/FN8w==**

Im aware that there could be a character encoding problem.  I've tried adding UTF8 and others to the getBytes(), but haven't found a way to return the same value in CF and Straight Java.

If anyone can shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: String salt = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(filename.getBytes()));      You are not getting the byes from the file in this statement, but rather the bytes that make up the string "foo".  And why do you use the same variable, "filename" for the password?

Comment: in my code the value i am passing in is just a filename. like foo.htm.   I needed something to pass in, so i decided to use the filename. That is why the variable name is filename. I replaced it in this example with just a foo string.  Can you elaborate on the bytes from the foo string instead of the file?

Comment: you want to base64 DECODE "foo" --> direclty to a byte array, and use that byte array directly as the argumetn to PBEKeyspec.  At least that is what genAESKeyFromPW() will do if you pass "foo" in as the argument for salt64.   Currently the code is getting the bytes that encode foo as ASCII, then *ENCODING* those as base64 (wrong direction), then getting the bytes for that, again as ASCII bytes.

Comment: Looks like I don't need to do anything with "foo"  I can just use that as the salt, and it returns the same.  I think I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code, and the values from it, in both:

```
    // The password
    String passwordString = "foo";

    // Base64 encoded random bytes used for the SALT.
    String saltString = "1234567890";

    char[] passwordChars = passwordString.toCharArray();
    byte[] saltBytes = Base64.decode(saltString);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChars, saltBytes, 1024, 128);
    SecretKey secret = factory.generateSecret(spec);

    System.out.println(Base64.encodeBytes(secret.getEncoded()));
```